# Separate DB for each branch in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, ef-code-first

I work with **MVC code first** and I us local DB (DB in app_data file) and I'm single programmer.

In visual studio, I create "**develop branch**" and change the database in develop.
then I checkout to master.
**BUT** Database changed for master and master need to "add migration" and "update database"

that's the problem that goes along with every checkout.
as Microsoft says, each branch, need to separate DB.

> Can I have separate db for each branch?

notice: I work with local db and I dont have microsoft sql server management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have different code bases on both branches. This of course is why you have separated branches on the first place.

Code first controls your database comparing your migrations with __MigrationHistory table, which is automatically created when use are using code first approach.

Even using localDb you could create separate DBs for each branch. You can use Sql Server Object Explorer from within Visual Studio. Create your two databases there, instead of under app_data.

Then for every branch you can have a different connection string in your config file. Same connection string key, but pointing to a different DB.